# How can I delay a http request?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-express

I am currently testing the loading-behaviour of a website. Particularly I would like to test the FOUT ([Description](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/)) in different browsers (FF, IE, Safari, Opera). In order to do that, I need to artificially delay the request that retrieves the font from the server.

Is there any predefined tool or way to achieve that?

My environment is ASP.NET with Visual Studio and the IIS-Express. I don't really want to implement a HttpHandler, since getting all the response-parameters perfectly right seems to be quiet hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHy not proxy all your traffic through Fiddler and either use the throttling option to slow down all traffic, or put a [breakpoint on the request](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-08-20/breakpoints-in-fiddler) for the font(s)?

Comment: One reason is that I did not know this. I'll have a look.

Comment: haha. Fiddler is a FANTASTIC app for this kind of thing - I'd recommend you get to know it as it will soon become an essential tool for you. BTW: its completely free - download link here: http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a dalayed response at http://www.deelay.me/

*Eg: http://deelay.me/1000/https://google.com/*

The google webpage will load after 1000 ms -> 1 sec